# Using Twilio API

Tags: api, twilio

I want to intercept a call towards a twillio phone number, log it and forward the call to another number.

If I don't pass it, it can be done easily with `response.record()` function.

How can it be solved with forwarding functionality?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking here. You have a Twilio phone number and you want to deal with incoming calls by forwarding them to another number? What language are you using and what have you tried so far? Have you checked out our [call forwarding tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/call-forwarding-nodejs-express)?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of  ways to do that for example :

1. Using TwilMl Dial verb , create a twilMl and assign it  to webhook on incoming calls. in this case the log of the call being received and forwarded is the voice log  https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial
2. Using Twilio studio , https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/how-to-forward-calls
   in the is case ,to log custom event you can create a Twilio function and use it in the flow.